# Physics and Chemistry Animations in After Effects

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-expressions

Are there any plugins/physics simulation engines other than Newton that will be useful for creating Physics and Chemistry content in After Effects?? 
For example, if I have a requirement to create the motion of electrons in an atom, how do I go about it?

Comment: Isn't the motion of electrons best described as a probability cloud? Gaussian Blur would be the effect I'd be using for that (comes with AE).

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of physics engines and related scripts available in the [Physics Simulation category at AEScripts](http://aescripts.com/after-effects/animation/physics-simulation/).

However, without a more specific question about what kind of animation you're looking for (that is to say, I don't know how the electrons in an atom are supposed to move), it's hard to point you to a specific answer.